# Drawing multiple triangles in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm just starting out with OpenGL and I have made my own 'OOP' version of drawing a triangle in c++.

I am using glfw and glew if that matters.

I don't understand why I can't draw more than 1 triangle.

This is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    Graphics::Window window(1280, 720, "Take me to heaven");
    window.MakeOpenGLAvailable(); // makes context with OpenGL after which initializes GLEW

    Graphics::Objects::Triangle firstTriangle(Graphics::Vec2( 0.0f,  0.0f),
                                              Graphics::Vec2( 1.0f,  1.0f),
                                              Graphics::Vec2(-1.0f,  1.0f));

    Graphics::Objects::Triangle secondTriangle(Graphics::Vec2( 0.0f,  0.0f),
                                               Graphics::Vec2(-1.0f, -1.0f),
                                               Graphics::Vec2( 1.0f, -1.0f));

    window.SetBackground(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    while (!window.isClosed() && !window.isKeyPressed(256)/*Escape*/)
    {
        window.DrawBackGround();

        firstTriangle.Draw();
        secondTriangle.Draw();

        window.Update();
        window.CheckForEvents();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the constructor looks like for the triangle class:

```
namespace Graphics { namespace Objects {

Triangle::Triangle(Vec2& a, Vec2& b, Vec2& c, bool normalised, short drawtype)
            : points{ a, b, c }
        {
            glGenBuffers(1, &this->triangleID);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->triangleID);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vec2) * 3, points, (drawtype == 0) ? GL_STATIC_DRAW : ((drawtype == 1) ? GL_STREAM_DRAW : GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW));

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, (normalised == false) ? GL_FALSE : GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vec2), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the draw method for the triangle class:

```
void Triangle::Draw()
        {
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->triangleID);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        }
```

This is the prototype for the Triangle class if that helps:

```
    class Triangle : public Shape
            {
            public:
                Triangle();
                Triangle(Vec2& a, Vec2& b, Vec2& c, bool normalised = false, short drawtype = 0);
                virtual ~Triangle();

                void Prepare(); // this just binds the buffer though I didn't use it since I bound the buffer inside the Draw method
                void Draw();

            private:
                Vec2 points[3];
                unsigned int triangleID;
}
```

I will give away more code if necessary, but the thing is that the program only draws the secondTriangle and I don't seem to understand why...
The majority of tutorials on the internet that I have come accross just define something like an array of floats with 6 vertex positions and instead of calling

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
```

they call

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // 12 etc.
```

What is stopping the first triangle from being drawn? Or is it being drawn and I can't see it? Am I doing anything stupid?

Comment: @Rabbid76 He is, it's in the constructor.  Should be in the draw command though.

Comment: Can you show your viewport setup?  I have a hunch that your triangles may be drawn but they are drawn at Z=0.0 so they are being culled.  Maybe try using Vec3 but setting the Z to `-1.0`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you so much for clarifying this to me. It works perfectly now! For some reason I thought that calling these two functions each time would be time consuming and that's why I called them inside the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Vertex array

e.g. Buffers for vertices (x, y, z), normals (x, y, z) and texture oordinates (u, v):

Draw the array:

```
GLsizei              no_of_points; // number of vertices and attrbuts
std::vector<GLfloat> vertex;       // linearized array (no_of_points * 3): [ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, .... ] 
std::vector<GLfloat> normal;       // linearized array (no_of_points * 3): [ Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, .... ] 
std::vector<GLfloat> color;        // linearized array (no_of_points * 5): [ R0, G0, B0, A0, R1, G1, B1, A1, .... ] 

GLuint vetexAttribIndex;  // index of the vertex attrbute (shader)
GLuint normalAttribIndex; // index of the normal attribute (shader)
GLuint colorAttribIndex;  // index of the color attribute (shader)

glVertexAttribPointer( vetexAttribIndex,  3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertex.data() ); // 3: Vx, Vy, Vz
glVertexAttribPointer( normalAttribIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE,  0, normal.data() ); // 3: Nx, Ny, Nz  -  GL_TRUE: values should be normalized
glVertexAttribPointer( colorAttribIndex,  4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, color.data() );  // 4: R, G, B, A 

glEnableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( colorAttribIndex );

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, no_of_points ); 

glDisableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( colorAttribIndex );
```

See:

- [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)
- [`glEnableVertexAttribArray` / `glDisableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml)
- [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml)

---

#### Vertex buffer object

The Khronos OpenGL wiki about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) clearly says:

> The [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) functions **state** where an attribute index gets its array data from.

This state can be retrieved with [`glGetVertexAttrib`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetVertexAttrib.xhtml).

More information about vertex attrbutes can be found in the [OpenGL 4.6. core specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) from Chapter 10.2 to 10.6.

e.g. Vertex, Normal vector and Texture coordiante

```
[ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Tv0, Tu0,
  Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, Tv1, Tu1,
  .....
]
```

Create the vertex array buffer:

```
GLsizei no_of_points;
std::vector<GLfloat> data; // attribute set: [ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Tv0, Tu0, Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, Tv1, Tu1, .... ]

GLuint vbo;

glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

See:

- [`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml)
- [`glDeleteBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteBuffers.xhtml)
- [`glBindBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml)

Draw the array:

```
GLuint vetexAttribIndex;  // index of the vertex attrbute (shader)
GLuint normalAttribIndex; // index of the normal attribute (shader)
GLuint texCorAttribIndex; // index of the texture coordinate attribute (shader)

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );

GLsizei stride = 8 * sizeof(GL_float); // size of one record in bytes: 8 * float [ Vx, Vy, Vz, Nx, Ny, Nz, Tv, Tu]
GLsizei offsV  = 0 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the vertex inside the reccord
GLsizei offsNV = 3 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the normal vector inside the reccord
GLsizei offsTC = 6 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the tecture coordinate inside the reccord

glVertexAttribPointer( vetexAttribIndex,  3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, offsV );  // 3: Vx, Vy, Vz
glVertexAttribPointer( normalAttribIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE,  stride, offsNV ); // 3: Nx, Ny, Nz  -  GL_TRUE: values should be normalized
glVertexAttribPointer( texCorAttribIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, offsTC ); // 2: Tu, Tv 

glEnableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( texCorAttribIndex );

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, no_of_points ); 

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( texCorAttribIndex );
```

---

#### Index buffer object

e.g. Vertex, Normal vector and Texture coordiante

```
[ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Tv0, Tu0,
  Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, Tv1, Tu1,
  .....
]
```

Create the vertex array buffer and the index buffer:

```
GLsizei no_of_points;
std::vector<GLfloat> data;    // attribute set: [ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Tv0, Tu0, Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, Tv1, Tu1, .... ]
std::vector<GLuint>  indices; // indces: [ I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, ..... ]

GLuint vbo;

glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

GLuint ibo;

glGenBuffers( 1, &ibo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

Draw the array:

```
GLuint vetexAttribIndex;  // index of the vertex attrbute (shader)
GLuint normalAttribIndex; // index of the normal attribute (shader)
GLuint texCorAttribIndex; // index of the texture coordinate attribute (shader)

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );

GLsizei stride = 8 * sizeof(GL_float); // size of one record in bytes: 8 * float [ Vx, Vy, Vz, Nx, Ny, Nz, Tv, Tu]
GLsizei offsV  = 0 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the vertex inside the reccord
GLsizei offsNV = 3 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the normal vector inside the reccord
GLsizei offsTC = 6 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the tecture coordinate inside the reccord

glVertexAttribPointer( vetexAttribIndex,  3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, offsV );  // 3: Vx, Vy, Vz
glVertexAttribPointer( normalAttribIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE,  stride, offsNV ); // 3: Nx, Ny, Nz  -  GL_TRUE: values should be normalized
glVertexAttribPointer( texCorAttribIndex,  2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, offsTC ); // 2: Tu, Tv 

glEnableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( texCorAttribIndex );

glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 ); 

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( texCorAttribIndex );
```

---

#### Vertex array object

To handle different vertex attribute pointers and not to specify and enable or disable them alternately, a vertex array object can be generated ([`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml), which stores all the information about buffer location, data format, state and attribute index:

See [OpenGL 4.6 core Specification - 10.3.1 Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> The buffer objects that are to be used by the vertex stage of the GL are collected together to form a vertex array object.
>   All state related to the definition of data used by the vertex processor is encapsulated in a vertex array object.
>
> ....
>
> The currently bound vertex array object is used for all commands which modify vertex array state, such as VertexAttribPointer and EnableVertexAttribArray;
>   all commands which draw from vertex arrays, such as DrawArrays and DrawElements;

e.g. Vertex, Normal vector and Texture coordiante

```
[ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Tv0, Tu0,
  Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, Tv1, Tu1,
  .....
]
```

Create the vertex array buffer and the index buffer:

```
GLsizei no_of_points;
std::vector<GLfloat> data;    // attribute set: [ Vx0, Vy0, Vz0, Nx0, Ny0, Nz0, Tv0, Tu0, Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, Tv1, Tu1, .... ]
std::vector<GLuint>  indices; // indces: [ I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, ..... ]

GLuint vbo;

glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

GLuint ibo;

glGenBuffers( 1, &ibo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

Create the vertex array object:

```
GLuint vao;

glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );

GLuint vetexAttribIndex;  // index of the vertex attrbute (shader)
GLuint normalAttribIndex; // index of the normal attribute (shader)
GLuint texCorAttribIndex; // index of the texture coordinate attribute (shader)

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );

GLsizei stride = 8 * sizeof(GL_float); // size of one record in bytes: 8 * float [ Vx, Vy, Vz, Nx, Ny, Nz, Tv, Tu]
GLsizei offsV  = 0 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the vertex inside the reccord
GLsizei offsNV = 3 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the normal vector inside the reccord
GLsizei offsTC = 6 * sizeof(GL_float); // offset of the tecture coordinate inside the reccord

glVertexAttribPointer( vetexAttribIndex,  3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, offsV );  // 3: Vx, Vy, Vz
glVertexAttribPointer( normalAttribIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE,  stride, offsNV ); // 3: Nx, Ny, Nz  -  GL_TRUE: values should be normalized
glVertexAttribPointer( texCorAttribIndex,  2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, offsTC ); // 2: Tu, Tv 

glEnableVertexAttribArray( vetexAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( normalAttribIndex );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( texCorAttribIndex );

glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo ); // Associate the element array buffer (index buffer) to the vertex array object

glBindVertexArray( 0 ); // Unbind the vertex array object

glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 ); // Unbinde the element array buffer. This has to be done after the vertex array object is unbound, otherwise the association to the vertex array object would be lost.
```

See:

- [`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml)
- [`glBindVertexArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexArray.xhtml)
- [`glDeleteVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteVertexArrays.xhtml)

Draw the array:

```
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr );
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

---

Note, in compare to the [index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), the [vertex buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) binding (`ARRAY_BUFFER`) is a global state.
Each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different `ARRAY_BUFFER`. This reference is stored when [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called, then the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is associated to the specified attribute index and the name (value) of the object is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO.
But the index buffer is a state of the VAO. When a buffer is bound to the target `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then this buffer is associated to the vertex array object which is currently bound.

Comment: I will definitely check this answer tomorrow, since now it's getting late in my country. The problem for me with the documentation websites for OpenGL is that they explain things in a formal way which is extremely confusing for me